# How to render checkbox on the <Image> (React Native)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I want to put checkbox on the Image. Here is current Screen.

[image]

It's simple `FlatList`. Here is `renderItem()` for FlatList

```
   <TouchableWithoutFeedback
      onPress={() => this._handleImagePress(item.id)}>
      <Image
        key={item.id}
        source={{uri: item.outfit_img}}
        style={styles.rowImage}
        resizeMode="cover"
      />
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

What I want to implement is like this screen below

[image]

I have `<CheckBox on={true}>` component to render **checked** checkbox.

**Requested**

```
handleImagePress = (id) => {
    if(_.includes(this.state.selectedIds, id)) {
        let newSelectedIds = _.filter(this.state.selectedIds, (curObject) => {
            return curObject !== id;
        });
        this.setState({selectedIds : newSelectedIds});
      } else {
        let newSelectedIds = [...this.state.selectedIds, id];
        this.setState({selectedIds : newSelectedIds});
      }
}
```

Comment: I've googled this problem for an hour :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to do this in your `renderItem()`:

```
renderItem({item}) => {
 const isSelected = this.state.selectedIds.includes(item.id)
 return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback
      onPress={() => this._handleImagePress(item.id)}
    >
       <Image
         key={item.id}
         source={{uri: item.outfit_img}}
         style={styles.rowImage}
         resizeMode="cover"
       />
       { isSelected && <CheckBox on={true}> }
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
 )
}
```

Here `Checkbox` should have `absolute` positioning, and you can provide your desired styles. Also, you need to add an `extraData` prop with value `this.state.selectedphotos` to your Flatlist.

Comment: Yeah I thought i should just answer, but as expected you are adding the ids to an array. you named it `selectedIds`

Comment: You mean I need to put style={{absolute:true, x, y}}?? <- This is actual question. Sorry if it was not clear to you

Comment: `style={{position:'absolute'}}` this will place the checkbok in the top left corner of the image. You can than accordingly add margins to place it to the top right corner.

Comment: Nice. I accepted your answer but you may want to edit it with style for further vote up :P Thank you

Comment: @JohnBaek can you provide the code for you checkbox component?

Comment: Actually it's from 'react-native-check-box' pkg library